# Aggregate duplicate records with Linq in polymorphic case

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to aggregate records stored in a `List<>`.

In the case I got a `List<int>`, the solution would be

```
var results = list.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => g.Sum());
```

In the case I got a `List<MyObject>` with

```
public class MyObject
{
   public MyObject(int pvalue)
   {
      Value = pvalue;
   }

   public int Value {get; set;}

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       var p = obj as MyObject;
       if (p == null)
          return false;

       return Value.Equals(p.Value);
   }

   public bool Equals(MyObject p)
   {
     if (p == null)
        return false;

     return Value.Equals(p.Value)
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
     int hash = 13;
     hash = (hash * 7) + Value.GetHashCode();
     return hash;
   }
 }
```

Then a solution would be :
`myOjectList.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(g => new MyObject{ Value = g.Sum()});`

Now in the case I got a `List<IMyObject>`, `IMyObject` being an interface (or an abstract class), and its concrete implementations got specific properties (example classes below), how can I solve the polymorphism in the `Select` of the previous Linq statement ?

```
public interface IMyObject
{
   int Value {get; set;}
   bool Equals(object obj);
   int GetHashCode();
}

public class MyObject1 : IMyObject
{
   public MyObject1(int pvalue, string pname)
   {
      Value = pvalue;
      Name = pname;
   }

   public int Value {get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       var p = obj as MyObject1;
       if (p == null)
          return false;

       return Name.Equals(p.Name) && Value.Equals(p.Value);
  }

  public bool Equals(MyObject1 p)
  {
     if (p == null)
        return false;

     return Name.Equals(p.Name) && Value.Equals(p.Value)
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
     int hash = 13;
     hash += (hash * 7) + Value.GetHashCode();
     hash += (hash * 7) + Name.GetHashCode();
     return hash;
  }
}

public class MyObject2 : IMyObject
{
   public MyObject2(int pvalue, int pvalue2)
   {
      Value = pvalue;
      Value2 = pvalue2;
   }

   public int Value {get; set;}
   public string Value2 { get; set; }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       var p = obj as MyObject1;
       if (p == null)
          return false;

       return Value2.Equals(p.Value2) && Value.Equals(p.Value);
  }

  public bool Equals(MyObject1 p)
  {
     if (p == null)
        return false;

     return Value2.Equals(p.Value2) && Value.Equals(p.Value)
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
     int hash = 13;
     hash += (hash * 7) + Value.GetHashCode();
     hash += (hash * 7) + Value2.GetHashCode();
     return hash;
  }
}
```

Comment: When sharing code, at least, make sure its working. your code has compile time errors so do not expect people to fix such errors for you.

Comment: It got compile time errors ? Oops, sorry. Should be fixed now

Comment: @YthioCsi `MyObject2` has errors yet. For example in the constructor you call a never-defined parameter.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus I see, copy paste mistakes from `MyObject1`, so sorry

Comment: @YthioCsi did you try our solutions? Did they work? Do you need more help?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Sorry i had a public holiday and stuff, didn't get back to it until know. The problem with solutions proposed is that they don't solve the problem of which child class constructor to call (i didn't try the clone solution yet)

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST SOLUTION: *REFLECTION***

```
myListOfIMyObjects
    .GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
    .Select(x =>
        {
            var constr = x.Key.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            var instance = (IMyObject)constr.Invoke(new object[0]);
            instance.Value = x.Select(o => o.Value).Sum();
            return instance;
        })
    .ToList();
```

**Pro**: you can embed all in a single `Select`, valid for all types implementing `IMyObject`, and you don't have to modify it if you add other classes like `MyObject3` or `MyObject4` later.

**Con**: Reflection is a fragile pattern, because you cannot rely on compilation checks. Also, all the `MyObject` classes *must* expose a parameterless constructor, and if it is not so, you will see an error only at runtime.

---

**SECOND SOLUTION: `OfType`**

```
var result1 = myListOfIMyObjects.OfType<MyObject1>();
var o1 = new MyObject1 { Value = result1.Sum(x => x.Value) };

var result2 = myListOfIMyObjects.OfType<MyObject2>();
var o2 = new MyObject2 { Value = result2.Sum(x => x.Value) };

var result = new List<IMyObject> { o1, o2 };
```

**Pro**: you have the compile-time checks, and the classes implementing `IMyObject` can have different constructors with different parameters.

**Con**: It's more verbose (you cannot embed that code in a single `Select`!), and if you add later other `MyObject3`, `MyObject4` in your domain, you have to come back here and add other rows manually.

Comment: How can I know if i need to call MyObject1 or MyObject2 ?

Comment: @YthioCsi it's not clear to me what kind of result you want to achieve. Pretend that in your list you have 2 `MyObject1` with `Value` 1 and 2, and 2 `MyObject2` with `Value` 3 and 4. What list should be produced?

Comment: @YthioCsi I've updated my answer, guessing what's your need. Lst me see what you think.

Comment: Let's assume for simplicity sake that the myListOfIMyObjects elements are all of the same IMyObjects implementation (all MyObject1 or all MyObject2). If i have 5 MyObject1 with values 1, 2, 3, 1, 1 i would like as a result, a list of 3 MyObject1 with values 3 (1+1+1), 2 and 3 for exemple. Is it clearer ? Sorry for not being clear the first time

Comment: @YthioCsi, things are getting clearer. What if you have 2 `MyObject1` and 3 `MyObject2` in the list? I guess you want as a result a list of 2 element, 1 `MyObject1` with a `Value` that is the sum of the 2 `MyObject1`, and 1 `MyObject2` with a `Value` that is the sum of the 3 `MyObject2`. Am I right?

Comment: In my context, business rules prevent different types in the list, they are all implementations of `IMyObject` interface, but `MyObject1` and `MyObject2` aren't mixed (it is one type exclusive or the other type). However, the mix case is interesting (may happen in the future ? And i'm curious), so yes, if there is  2 `MyObject1` and 3 `MyObject2`, the result should be 1 `MyObject1` with a Value that is the sum of the 2 `MyObject1`, and 1 `MyObject2` with a Value that is the sum of the 3 `MyObject2`

Comment: I got null reference exception on constr with the reflection method, it should be specific to the myObject implementation because there is more arguments than Type.EmptyTypes, however if I specify explicitly the arguments type, i'm back to the beginning, isn't it ?
Solution 2 would cause problem if MyObject3, MyObject4, etc... are added in the future i think

Comment: @YthioCsi, that's because your `MyObject1`and `MyObject2` have only constructors with parameters. As I said, you should implement on those classes a parameter-less constructor. Seen your code, I don't think such a constructor would break your design.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new operation to `IMyObject` to `Clone` the object:

```
public interface IMyObject {
    int Value { get; set; }
    bool Equals(object obj);
    int GetHashCode();
    IMyObject Clone();
}
```

Implement the `Clone` method:

```
public class MyObject1 : IMyObject {
    ...
    public IMyObject Clone() {
        return (IMyObject)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class MyObject2 : IMyObject {
    ...
    public IMyObject Clone() {
        return (IMyObject)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `Clone` method to create an object to return (NOTE: you said nothing about how to pick the proper values for the other properties, so I arbitrarily used the first object in each group as the source).

```
var ans = myObjectList.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(g => { var rtnval = g.First().Clone(); rtnval.Value = g.Sum(m => m.Value); return rtnval; });
```

Comment: I tried but it got duplicates here and there, which is weird, i'm trying to find why